# Managing private channel membership with Slack bot that can't be kicked by users

Tags: slack, slack-api

Requirement: Continuously manage membership of a private channel based on external-to-slack criteria, preventing channel members from kicking the bot from the channel!

I can't find a way to meet:

1. Allow a Slack bot to manage a private channel it's a member of: inviting and kicking users at-will,
2. Prevent users of the channel from kicking the Slack bot.

Under `Settings & Permissions -> Permissions -> Channel Management` there's the **People  who can remove members from private channels:** option.

If I choose **Everyone**, then

1. Is satisfied: bot can kick users,
2. Isn't satisfied: Users can kick the bot.

If I choose **Workspace Admins and Owners only**, then

1. Isn't satisfied: bot can't kick users because it's not admin or owner,
2. Is satisfied: Users can't kick the bot!

Would love a workaround this this...

Answer (score 1):

Solution was at Oauth request time ask for the `groups:write` scope for both the bot **and** the user. Then when making the `conversations.kick` API call pass the user token (who has Owner or Admin privileges).

Following this approaches lets your bot (acting as the user who installed it) to kick private channel members when **People who can remove members from private channels** = **Workspace Admins and Owners only**.

Comment: What bot are you using?